# Issues setting up CKAN virtual environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, ckan

I'm following the [Prepare to Use Extensions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.4.3/prepare-extensions.html) document and I'm having issues installing CKAN into a virtual environment.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip mercurial
virtualenv /home/ubuntu/pyenv
. /home/ubuntu/pyenv/bin/activate
```

At first this failed, but then I found that *virtualenv* should be *python-virtualenv*.

Now I'm having issues with:

```
pip install -e hg+http://bitbucket.org/okfn/ckan#egg=ckan
```

I'm getting an error code 255, and when I visit the URL, it looks like the source has been deleted and moved to Github. I'm a beginner to Ubuntu, Python and CKAN so I'm not sure how to properly change this command to point to the new location.

I tried to use the following, but it didn't work for me:

```
pip install -e hg+https://github.com/ckan/ckan#egg=ckan
```

How should I continue to install CKAN in the virtual environment?

Comment: This is a really old version of the docs! Follow the latest version and it will save you a lot of trouble: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to that URL in your browser, you will see it has a pointer to github now:

> This repository has been deleted
>   Our apologies, but the repository "ckan" has been deleted.
>   It now lives at https://github.com/okfn/ckan.

So, instead you do:

```
 pip install -e 'git+git://github.com/ckan/ckan#egg=Package'
```

or

```
 pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/ckan/ckan#egg=Package'
```

I quoted the URL as a good practice (because # is comment character in the shell), but in this context it isn't interpreted that way, so it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I'm getting the following error for your first suggestion:

    Cannot find command 'git'
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/yee_s/.pip/pip.log

For the second suggestion, I get:

    Cannot find command 'git'
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/yee_s/.pip/pip.log

Comment: You'll need to install git:  `sudo apt-get install git`